# Use gparted to shrink entire disk image?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I have taken an image of a friend's windows disk. I do mean image of the *disk*, not just the partition that is the C: drive. Consequently the image has about five partitions in it, including at least two recovery partitions, partition table, and a master boot record.

The original drive is 1 Tb spinning rust. I think the disk might possibly be dying (it's running very slow, like it's doing retries, though SMART reports it as OK) or perhaps it's just a really low performance slow-spinner. Whether it is dying or not, my goal is to get this onto an SSD. However, since he's using barely 80 Gb of the drive, I want to give him a 1/4 Tb SSD that I'm not using, rather than make him fork over for a whole new, excessively large, drive.

So, the plan is to resize the main C: partition, move up the other partitions and correct the partition table so the resulting device image can be put onto the new device. I suppose I will need to do something to correct the boot records too after all of this.

Is this a practical proposition using gparted? The device image is currently copying onto an ext4 partition on a large USB drive, but if I'm on a loser, I would like to know so I don't waste hours banging my head against it. On the other hand, if it's doable, any pointers would be welcome.

EDIT:
Responses to questions in comments

1. The original device has several partitions, the main one--that is, the large one I wish to resize-is ntfs, the others are ... well, I don't actually know for sure, they're the "extra" stuff that Windows uses for boot, and restoration partitions.
2. I have used dd to take an image of the original device (my system, on which I'm performing this is Linux, and I booted the windows system with a Linux install disk to make the image).

Additional info/progress

1. I realize I entirely omitted to describe that I'm working on the image in my Linux system (since that's what I know :) So, hoping to use gparted for this, but ready enough to use some other Linux tool if needed.
2. I would really prefer not to change the original disk, but simply to create a viable image and place that on the SSD and then see if that boots. If/when this works, I would simply include his existing disk as a secondary drive in case he ever needs the storage.
3. I have succeeded in mounting the device image using loopback, as I determined that gparted won't work directly on a file (seems like an odd omission, but whatever)
4. gparted has been willing to accept instructions to shrink the C: partition and to move the three (unknown type) partitions that follow it. It's still executing the shrink operation, so it'll be a while before I find out if it completes.
5. The resize/moves appeared to complete, and the resulting image booted right away. However, there seems to be something wrong or corrupted, as many programs don't start, and one actually complains about being corrupted. All that's very odd, as a) windows started without any complaint, and b) several programs (Chrome, OpenOffice) start and run just fine. I wonder if the disk is indeed failing, and the dd process didn't do retries and somehow read bad data. I'm not sure what to make of this situation.

TIA
Toby

Comment: what's the format of the image file ? which software did you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a device image is a good idea, let that finish.

Resizing partitions and moving partitions is a risky operation. Personally I don't consider it practical.

I would have used a legacy version of Acronis True Image to create a backup and then restore that backup file to the new SSD. If you let True Image backup only the used clusters of your volumes (assuming it supports your file systems used on your source drive) you can change the sizes of the target partitions upon restore.

You can run Acronis off a live system if you want.
Unfortunately Acronis seems to have become fat and less reliable over time.
Paragon Software has a similar product. Another product I heard of is Macrium Reflect, but I can't tell you if they support linux type file systems.

If you have special software installed that use unused sectors between partitions as copy protection you would run into problems though.